# radare2: How to load a DLL along with the application?

Tags: disassembly, radare2, dll

I am reverse engineering a Windows application for which there is no PDB file available.
When loading it in r2, I get the following imports (They are correct):

```
 nth  vaddr      bind type lib          name
―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
545  0x00012008 NONE FUNC COREDLL.dll  Ordinal_545
557  0x0001200c NONE FUNC COREDLL.dll  Ordinal_557
```

Stub functions are called in the disassembly, like this

```
bl fcn.000111c8
```

and fcn.000111c8 essentially loads the address and calls the actual function

```
┌ 12: fcn.000111c8 ();                                                          
│           0x000111c8           ldr ip, sym.imp.COREDLL.dll_Ordinal_545
│           0x000111cc           ldr ip, [ip]               
└           0x000111d0           bx ip
```

I have the COREDLL.dll file and it contains correct debug symbols. I would like to tell r2 to use them to get the function names for these plt entries, so that I see the real function names from the DLLs instead of generated names like "Ordinal_xxx".

How do I do that?